# How to debug tcl/tk code used between C and R

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I was given a program that utilizes C, tcl/tk, and R code. tcl/tk is interlaced in both the C and R code. Tcl/tk creates a bridge between the R and C code so to speak. The C code generates a .dll which is then used for functions called in R. There are some bugs with the program though, and I would like to attempt to debug it. However, adding print statements and whatnot in the C code will not appear in the R or C output. Is there a way to actualize the debugging results done in C in R using tcl/tk?

Comment: I'm not clear on the flow of control here. Is it R functions invoking Tcl procedures that in turn invoke the C code? Also, adding print statements to the C code that print to the standard output does show up somewhere, so I'm not sure what it means to "actualize the debugging results". Perhaps you could explain a bit more.

Comment: I'd just like to preface that I'm an undergrad student that was sorta of just thrown into this. I don't know a whole lot about C. Yes, both a Tcl package in R as well as `tcl.h` in C are being utilized. I do not see any output from the C code, as no `main` function is being used. Upon running "Local Windows Debugger" in visual studio, it succeeds the build, but states that .dll is not a valid win32 application. So I do not see any output.

Comment: Does seem you landed in the deep end of the pool. The integration of three languages can certainly be a tricky situation. Debugging it will depend upon specific code details which aren't here. As you continue your exploration of how the program works, perhaps more specific questions will crop up for which you can supply definite code sequences which can be answered here.

Comment: There will be a main somewhere, but it might not help. Focus instead on where information passes between the languages. Those boundaries are key places to understand the APIs that the various pieces have with each other.

Comment: One bit of code that seems to be doing a lot of work in the C code is `#define TCL_CMD(name) int name(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])`. `objv` seems to be the arguments passed in R functions that are then read into the C code using this `TCL_CMD` method. I can provide more details later. I hope this helps at all in terms of how these languages are talking to each other.